# Capitalize first letter using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to capitalize first letter of sentence for every class.

I have html `<span class="price"></span>` multiple time on my page and I want to capitalize first letter of every tag. So I have an array of span classes.

Default value of html elements is lowercase, I tried with text-transform:capitalize, it converts first letter of every word.

I tried to write some code but it doesn't work, it goes through loop only once and it doesn't work.

Here is the code, can somebody help me to modify to work

```
function applySentenceCase() {
    var selector = document.getElementsByClassName('price');
    for( i =0; i<selector.length; i++) {
      var selectorTest = jQuery(selector[i]).text();
      return selectorTest.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + selectorTest.substr(1).toLowerCase();

        }
    }
```

Comment: You sure are replacing the characters, but where exactly do you think you're returning the string ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why not stick with jQuery, as you're already using it

```
$('.price').text(function(_, txt) {
    return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.slice(1).toLowerCase();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I complicated everything with a loop. This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with CSS:

```
.price:first-letter{
   text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Iam not sure what you get with your document.getElementsByClassName('price');
but this work it will return Toto

```
function applySentenceCase() 
{
   var selector = "toto";
   return selector.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + selector.substr(1).toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: With document.getElementsByClassName('price'); I'm getting all html elements which strings want to change to capitalize. I have few divs with class.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is basically right. I imagine there is a problem with the jquery? I changed it a tiny bit to use javascript. https://jsfiddle.net/h6h4nswd/

```
var selectorTest = selector[i].innerHTML;
```

Comment: I know that I'm missing something, but I didn't know what. :) This is definitely peace of code I needed. :) Thank you.